# Cell (Expandable) content overlaps while editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios8

I have this UITableView which is displaying cells with Dynamic Height.

When Editing control is been clicked, it shows all the content of the cell.

[image]  [image]

**Why is this happening? What is the solution for this?**

- `cell`'s `clipsToBounds` property is set to `YES`.
- `cell.contentView`'s `clipsToBound` property is set to `YES`.
- `tableView`'s delegate method for cell height is returning a constant value - 100.0f.

Comment: please upload some code

Comment: tell me what code should I show? For your information, when delete control is clicked, `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`, `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `willDisplayCell` doesn't get called

Comment: There is basically no code, everything is done in xib. In the delegate, cell height is set to a constant value to 100.0f

Comment: Did you set leading constraints?

Comment: My guess is your constraints are wrong. Check out this tutorial:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift  Specifically, see the "pro tips" notes, which give advice on how to setup constraints.